# How to set up timing tasks in Mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I have an application and I want to run the scheduled task separately. So, I need to refresh the DateTime time in Mysql every 1 hour, and then judge the TODO based on the time. I am not sure which package to use, is there a recommendation? If I don't rely on code to perform timing tasks, is it possible? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use code to implement scheduled tasks in Asp.net core, you can use the following packages:

**Quartz** ：

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html#download-and-install

**Hangfire** ：

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html

**TimedJob**：

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimedJob/

Personally, if you just need to update your database DateTime every hour, I would recommend TimedJob because it is too convenient to use.

I made a simple demo here, you can refer to it：

**Configure in the Startup class**：

1.Configure application services in the ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddTimedJob();
```

2.Create the application's request processing pipeline in the Configure method.

```
app.UseTimedJob();
```

**Create a class to write timer code**

```
 public class Schedule : Job
    {
        [Invoke(Begin = "2022-01-05 9:00", Interval = 60*60, SkipWhileExecuting = true)]
        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            TaskA();
        }

        private void TaskA()
        {
            //Execute your update sql statement
            Console.WriteLine("Task A:Successfully updated DateTime!");
        }
      
    }
```

In order to facilitate the demonstration effect, the setting time is shorter. If it takes 1 hour, set it to `60 * 60 * 1000`.

In addition, I did not do database operations here, you can execute your sql statement in the TaskA method.

Result:

[image]

There are two ways to implement MySQL timing tasks:

1.Use MySQL event timing tasks
To use MySQL's event schedule, you first need to enable event_scheduler on the
server before it can be processed.

2.Use Linux's timing task crontab

This article has detailed examples, you can read it, I hope these are helpful to you：

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: Thanks, it can work. But if there is an accident in the program, are there any measures?

Comment: You can try to do a message notification, and send the notification even after the exception is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an event:

```sql
CREATE EVENT update_todos
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO 
BEGIN
   -- your query here;
END;
```

Also, make sure that the event scheduler is turned on. The event_scheduler system variable can be set in a configuration file:

```
[mysql]
event_scheduler=ON
```

The event_scheduler system variable can also be set dynamically at runtime by executing SET GLOBAL:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Mysql, you can create an [EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) that will be triggered based on specific conditions that you decide (Daily, each hour, and on a specific date, etc...)

Or, if you can schedule some scripts on your server, in the case of Linux, you can use [CRON Jobs](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux), and in the case of windows, you can check the [Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Enjoy Coding!